# monogame sprite movement not smooth using delta

Tags: c#, monogame

I am new to monogame and c#

I was updating a sprite X for movement however is it not smooth, so i have tried using delta gametime, however it does not seem any better, I am making a noob mistake no doubt but can not suss it, any help would be very much appreciated, thank you

My Update is as follows

```
var delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;


            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                vecPlayerPostion.X -= 1  * delta;
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
            {
                vecPlayerPostion.X += 1 * delta;
            }
```

and draw is

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texPlayerTexture, vecPlayerPostion, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

and if needed my whole code is as follows

game1.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace SpaceShip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        PlayerShip PlayerShipUser1;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;  // set this value to the desired width of your window
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;   // set this value to the desired height of your window
            graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
            graphics.ApplyChanges();

            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here


            PlayerShipUser1 = new PlayerShip();
            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            PlayerShipUser1.texPlayerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here
            PlayerShipUser1.Update(gameTime);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            PlayerShipUser1.Draw(spriteBatch);

            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

playershipclass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
namespace SpaceShip
{
    class PlayerShip
    {
        public Texture2D texPlayerTexture;

        private Vector2 vecPlayerPostion;

        public PlayerShip()
        {
            vecPlayerPostion.X = 800;
            vecPlayerPostion.Y = 900;

        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            var delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;


            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            {
                vecPlayerPostion.X -= 1  * delta;
            }
            else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) 
            {
                vecPlayerPostion.X += 1 * delta;
            }

        }


        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {

            spriteBatch.Draw(texPlayerTexture, vecPlayerPostion, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I think this might be more to do with animation techniques than code. You can't really break the 60 fps limit so when you're animating fast objects you might want to consider using motion blur or squash and stretch animations. It's not easy, but it will make a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with your code is the movement speed is too fast.  At 60 fps, the `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` is 16.  This results in a jump of 16 pixels per step(or 1000 pixels per second), which breaks visual continuity.

I usually limit the speed of objects to 4-8 pixels per step.
To implement this change the delta multiplier from `1`to `0.25f` or `0.5f`.

```
// Set speed to 4 pixels per step
vecPlayerPostion.X -= 0.25f  * delta;
```

---

If you need the speed to stay the same(fast), you can draw intermediate frames in the same step with reduced alpha. This technique causes a motion blur, but it reduces the jumpy appearance.

Update `playershipclass.cs` as follows:

```
  public Texture2D texPlayerTexture;

  private Vector2 vecPlayerPostion;

  // Store the previous position
  private Vector2 vecPlayerLastPostion;

  public PlayerShip()
  // ...

  public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
     // Store the value
     vecPlayerLastPostion = vecPlayerPostion;

     var delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

// ...

  public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
  {
     // Draw the texture halfway between the previous position and current at .4f alpha
     spriteBatch.Draw(texPlayerTexture, (vecPlayerPostion + vecPlayerLastPostion) / 2, null, new Color (1,1,1,0.4f), 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

     spriteBatch.Draw(texPlayerTexture, vecPlayerPostion, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);

  }
```

---

A third solution would be to unrestrict the frame rate:

In the constructor for game1:

```
// ...
 public Game1()
 {
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;  // set this value to the desired width of your window
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;   // set this value to the desired height of your window
    graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
    graphics.ApplyChanges();

    // Remove 60 fps target
    IsFixedTimeStep = false;

    // don't wait on vsync(will limit to 60 fps)
    graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;

    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried the above, I like the 0.25f look, however it moves across the screen a bit to slow, and if i try 0.50 it looks odd again, any ideas ?